# Best way to do navigation in a hybrid Cordova Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dom, navigation

I have some doubts about my project, I am making a small hybrid app, so far everything I am doing without PhoneGap, directly with PHP, HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript on my local server. Then I will use PhoneGap to turn my project into an application.

In my application there is a navbar with 3 tabs, my question is about the second tab, I explain how I imagine the structure should be:

When the user clicks on the second tab for the first time, the user should see a list, such as a menu of options:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
```

When clicking on any of those options on the same screen (tab 2) should change the "view" and display the suboptions of the chosen option, the structure is the following. For example, if you choose "Option A", you will see something like this:

```
Photo1
Name1
Link1

Photo2
First Name2
Link2

...

PhotoN
NameN
LinkN
```

I guess it would be great to do "pagination" since it is likely that each option has many suboptions and I do not want to saturate the memory.

Finally, when clicking on some of the Links, we will assume "Link1", in the same tab 2 I would like to see all the complete information about that element in the list. Obviously all that information is in a database. My question is:

### What is the best way to do the navigation of the interface I just raised?

I was thinking of making a "container" div on tab 2 and changing its DOM, but then I wonder how I will manage the "back" action - ie the "return" action and obviously the user will think he/she can return by pressing the Back button (in case of Android).

I must clarify that I am not using any framework like ionic, react or angular. ALl is from scratch, the only thing I use is jQuery.

Thanks for reading and please forgive my horrible way to write english.

Comment: Just a question, why would you not use a framework? It takes care of you navigation and other things, and you could still use jQuery.

Comment: @ThomasJuranek Because I have almost everything ready and I think implementing a framework will take more work/time because I must rewrite almost all. Or is it not? Which framework manages navigation well? can't I do this with only jQuery?

Comment: I don't have that much jQuery experience, but I think that the Ionic framework works really well for navigation and it uses Angular JS